# How to update and render a <b-img> element at set intervals using Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

JS and Vue beginner here. I'm working with Bootstrap-Vue and have an image element like this:

```html
<b-img src="/api/camera" fluid alt="camera"></b-img>
```

On page refresh, the browser pulls the image from `/api/camera`. I get a fresh image from the camera every time I refresh the page.

I'd like to have this image update at set intervals, e.g every second. I know how to run JS functions at set intervals using `setInterval()` and I already do so elsewhere in the app.

I did some research online and followed [Michael Thiessen's suggestion](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) to use the `:key` attribute, and increment it whenever I need an update:

```html
<b-img :key="camera_stream_key" src="/api/camera" fluid alt="camera"></b-img>
```

As a proof of concept, I tried doing this from a button:

```html
<b-button pill variant="success" size="md" @click="update_camera_stream()">Refresh</b-button>
```

```js
    update_camera_stream() {
      this.camera_stream_key += 1;
    }
```

Although I can confirm that clicking the button increments the key, it doesn't update the image.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating the src of the `<b-img>` with the key?

```html
<b-img :src="`/api/camera?${camera_stream_key}`" fluid alt="camera"></b-img>
```

This will force an update by changing the url (source) of the image. You could also use the current timestamp as a query parameter.

Comment: I haven't, and I just did. It works. Thank you!